# Converting .TIF to .PDF gives PIL: Error reading image

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion, python-imaging-library

I've been trying to batch process some .TIF files and convert them to PDFs. I did have it working, but then after trying to change img2pdf so it would accept larger files I was never able to get the same program running again, even after re-installing.

Currently this is throwing out the following error:

```
>>>>
ImageOpenError: cannot read input image (not jpeg2000). PIL: error reading image: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001A608255EB8>
```

Here is the code I've been using. Anyone got any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
import img2pdf, sys, os, time
image_directory = r"PATH"

image_files = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(image_directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".tif") or file.endswith(".TIF"):
             print("Discovered this TIF: ", os.path.join(root, file))
             image_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))

for image in image_files:
    output_file = image[:-4] + ".pdf"
    print ("Putting all TIFs into ", output_file)
    pdf_bytes = img2pdf.convert(image)
    file = open(output_file,"wb")
    file.write(pdf_bytes)
```

Here is the full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-37-fe96d5eeb049>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('PATH', wdir='PATH')

  File "PATH", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "PATH", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "PATH", line 23, in <module>
    pdf_bytes = img2pdf.convert(image_files)

  File "PATH", line 1829, in convert
    ) in read_images(rawdata, kwargs["colorspace"], kwargs["first_frame_only"]):

  File "PATH", line 1171, in read_images
    "PIL: error reading image: %s" % e

ImageOpenError: cannot read input image (not jpeg2000). PIL: error reading image: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001A6082BE3B8>
```

Comment: It seems that some image is "corrupted". Can you share the TIF file you're trying to convert?

P.S.: I've tried your code on some sample TIF file and it seems to be working pretty well.

Comment: I can't share the files no, but I have tried opening up the file and its perfectly viewable.

Comment: Tried it on the image at the top of the list here http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/sample/, still didnt work

Comment: Which version of Pillow are you using?

Comment: PIL.__version__:       Out[46]: '5.3.0'

Comment: Try upgrading to `Pillow==6.0.0` or `Pillow==6.1.0`.

Comment: So when i type pip install --upgrade Pillow i get that the requirement is already satisfied

Comment: Now trying to check my version of Pillow i get PIL is not defined....wtf is going on with my PC

Comment: Here's the command which you can use `pip install 'Pillow>=6.0.0' --force-reinstall`

Comment: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'Path'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: New error on the program too:  RuntimeWarning: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:
Core version: 5.3.0
Pillow version: 6.1.0 [Image.py:116]

Answer (score 4):

If, as I understand it, you want to recursively find all TIFF images and convert each one to a correspondingly named PDF file, you can do that simply and in parallel with **GNU Parallel** and **ImageMagick** like this in Terminal:

```
find . -iname "*tif" -print0 | parallel -0 --dry-run mogrify {} {.}.pdf
```

**Sample Output**

```
mogrify ./OpenCVTIFF64/result.tif ./OpenCVTIFF64/result.pdf
mogrify ./OpenCVTIFF64/a.tif ./OpenCVTIFF64/a.pdf
mogrify ./OpenCVBasics/a.tif ./OpenCVBasics/a.pdf
mogrify ./CImgDump/image.tif ./CImgDump/image.pdf
```

That command says... *"Starting in the current directory, recursively find all TIFF files, whether upper or lowercase or some mixture and pass their names, null-terminated, to **GNU Parallel**. It should then read each name and run **ImageMagick** `mogrify` to convert that TIFF into a file with same name but the extension replaced with `PDF`."*

If it does what you want, remove the `--dry-run` and do it again for real.

Comment: I managed to get the python script working, but Im having trouble processing large pictures with a high pixel count. Would this method be able to avoid that?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to have any problems, try it. If on **macOS**, use `brew install parallel imagemagick`

Comment: managed to avoid the decompression warning on python with Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None. Appreciate the help nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

So this ended up working once I executed pip install 'Pillow>=6.0.0' --force-reinstall, even though the command itself didn't execute properly. I get a few warnings when I run, but it's now working. Short version is, it was an issue with Pillow.